# Align multiple arrays vertically, which look like a pmatrix with a vertical line separator

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices, arrays

```
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
3&1&-2&1&0&0\\
-1&4&3&0&1&0\\
1&2&-1&0&0&1
\end{array}\right)
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
\\
\text{II+III}\\
\text{3III-I}
\end{array}\\

\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
3&1&-2&1&0&0\\
0&6&2&0&1&1\\
0&5&-1&-1&0&1
\end{array}\right)
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
\\
\text{}\\
\text{6III-5II}
\end{array}
\end{align}
```

If you render this, you will see that the vertical lines of both "arrays" don't line up. Even when I put a & before every \left(... it still doesn't align well, because of different cell widths. Since I am using [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/), I only have [these](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/index.html) extensions.

Comment: note mathjax specific questions are off topic but probably a latex solution that also works in mathjax is possible

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all the columns are the same width by adding phantom minus signs, and add an alignment point between the right ) and the text labels.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
3&\phantom{-}1&-2&\phantom{-}1&\phantom{-}0&\phantom{-}0\\
-1&4&3&0&1&0\\
1&2&-1&0&0&1
\end{array}\right)
  &
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
\\
\text{II+III}\\
\text{3III-I}
\end{array}\\
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
\phantom{-}3&\phantom{-}1&-2&\phantom{-}1&\phantom{-}0&\phantom{-}0\\
0&6&2&0&1&1\\
0&5&-1&-1&0&1
\end{array}\right)
  &
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
\\
\text{}\\
\text{6III-5II}
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this still work if one number has multiple digits?

Comment: @ConfusedLearner -- If there are multiple digits in one matrix and not the other, you'll have to add one or more phantom digits in some columns to force them to be the same width.

Answer (score 2):

Some observations, in no particular order:

- The `array` package provides a very useful column type: `w`, which lets you specify both a horizontal alignment -- `l`, `c`, or `r` -- and a fixed width (here: the width of a signed single-digit integer.  By using the `w` column type, you'll save yourself from having to enter a lot of instances of `\phantom{-}`.
- I can't see a reason for specifying 4 columns -- `rrr|r` -- for the secondary `array` environments; a single column -- presumably `l` -- will do just fine.
- You should use `\mathrm`, not `\text`, for the descriptors in the secondary arrays, the more so as `+` and `-` denote binary operators. This is particularly important to the `-` symbols, which will get rendered as text-mode hyphenation characters instead of as mathematical 'minus' symbols.
- If you're going to use an `align` environment, do make sure to specify (with the alignment marker symbol `&`) *where* the alignment points are supposed to be. If you don't do so, you'll get right-alignment, which hardly ever is what's meant to happen.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment
\usepackage{calc}    % for '\widthof' macro
\usepackage{array}   % for 'w' columnn type and '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{W}{w{r}{\widthof{$-1$}}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\left( \begin{array}{@{} WWW | WWW @{}}
   3&1&-2&1&0&0\\
  -1&4& 3&0&1&0\\
   1&2&-1&0&0&1
\end{array} \right)
\quad % horizontal distance between the 'array' environments
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
   \\
   \mathrm{II+III}\\
   \mathrm{3III-I}
\end{array}\\[\jot]  % end of first row
&\left( \begin{array}{@{} WWW | WWW @{}}
   3&1&-2& 1&0&0\\
   0&6& 2& 0&1&1\\
   0&5&-1&-1&0&1
\end{array} \right)
\quad
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
   \\
   \\
   \mathrm{6III-5II}
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sadly, I don't have the array package. Therefore, I cannot use \newcolumntype. How can I do this without it?

Comment: @ConfusedLearner - I suppose I was giving a solution that works with LaTeX. Trying to redo my solution without `\newcolumntype` would be very tedious. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do with `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\begin{align}
\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|rrr}[last-col]
3&1&-2&1&0&0 &~\rlap{\text{II+III}}\\
-1&4&3&0&1&0 &~\rlap{\text{3III-I}}\\
1&2&-1&0&0&1
\end{pNiceArray} \\
\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|rrr}[last-col]
3&1&-2&1&0&0\\
0&6&2&0&1&1\\
0&5&-1&-1&0&1 &~\rlap{\text{6III-5II}}
\end{pNiceArray}
\end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose a modification of F. Pantigny's excellent answer.

1. There's no need to use `\rlap`.
2. I'd use a command for the row numbers for denoting row operations; it eases input and also can be easily modified if you change your mind.

Indeed, using `\text{II+III}` gives wrong spacing around the + sign; worse, `\text{3III-I}` uses a hyphen rather than a minus sign. The command `\row` I define allows for properly using math mode and also for slightly detaching the row number (in Roman numerals) from the coefficient (if any).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\row}{m}{\mathop{{}\mathrm{\int_to_Roman:n{#1}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%% or, maybe
% \NewDocumentCommand{\row}{m}{R_{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\begin{align}
&\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|rrr}[last-col]
  3 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 4 &  3 & 0 & 1 & 0 &\quad  \row{2} + \row{3} \\
  1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &\quad 3\row{3} - \row{1} \\
\end{pNiceArray} \\
&\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|rrr}[last-col]
  3 & 1 & -2 &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 6 &  2 &  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 5 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 &\quad 6\row{3}-5\row{2}
\end{pNiceArray}
\end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I use the second possible definition, by uncommenting it and commenting out the first one, the output is, without *any* other change to the code,

[image]

Comment: although the Op wants a version that also works in mathjax (which is why I fell back to phantom)